# Flutter's svg image shows no errors but doesn't get displayed

Tags: flutter

I am trying to use svg image, it doesn't appear but doesn't show any errors.

```
const logo = 'images/logo.svg';
```

**this is my yaml file**

```
assets:
    - images/
```

**this is my code and in below if I put just logo instead of 'images/logo.svg' it shows error saying

```
'Unable to load asset: "logo".
      The asset does not exist or has empty data.
'
```

**

```
 Containers(
  width: size.width,
  color: Colors.amber,
  height: 115,
  child: SvgPicture.asset(
  'images/logo.svg',
  fit: BoxFit.fill,),
 ),
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have included flutter_svg to to your dependencies

import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart

Make sure the file path matches the location of the SVG file

if that doesn't work, there could be a problem with the svg file itself